# Some Julia packages support data having Float64 (single) format, bur I have data of having Float64 (dubble) format

Tags: julia

Julia audio read package WAV produce data in doubble precesion. If I want to use these data in other packges whose input data types are single precision data, it is showing error. My objective is to mantain a one type of precision data type such that all the function support the format.

I have tried to change the format WAV read output. I couldn't change it.

Now I want to know how I can change data type required in the package called TimeseriesSurrogate.

```
shuffled_data=TimeseriesSurrogates.randomshuffle(amp_env)
```

I expected to get a randomly shuffled data. It is showing the following error messages.

> MethodError: no method matching randomshuffle(::Array{Float64,2})
>   Closest candidates are:
>     randomshuffle(!Matched::UncertainData.UncertainDatasets.UncertainIndexDataset) at /home/rabindev/.julia/packages/TimeseriesSurrogates/Lofe0/src/uncertaindatasets.jl:15
>     randomshuffle(!Matched::UncertainData.UncertainDatasets.UncertainValueDataset) at /home/rabindev/.julia/packages/TimeseriesSurrogates/Lofe0/src/uncertaindatasets.jl:9
>     randomshuffle(!Matched::UncertainData.UncertainDatasets.UncertainDataset) at /home/rabindev/.julia/packages/TimeseriesSurrogates/Lofe0/src/uncertaindatasets.jl:3
>     ...
>
> Stacktrace:
>    [1] top-level scope at In[122]:2

Comment: Can you please provide example code that reproduces the problem? See here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge in Julia it doesn't exist a Float64(single) vs Float64(double) precision, just `Float64` (or `Float32`).

If you are interfacing with C libraries using `ccall`, the map rule is C `float` -> Julia `Float32` and C `double` -> `Float64`.

In within Julia, you can convert the two using `convert(T,x)`, although it shouldn't be needed:

```
a = 0.5
typeof(a) # Float64 by default
b = convert(Float32,a)
typeof(b) # Now it is a Float32
```

Edit:
In your case the problem seems that `randomshuffle` expects a single vector as argument (`Array{T,1}`), while you are providing it with a matrix (`Array{T,2}`).

You can see the methods provided by the function `randomshuffle` with `methods(randomshuffle)`, the 4th result being:

`randomshuffle(ts::AbstractArray{T,1} where T)`

Comment: Thank you, Antonello. I created a function where I give input of (Float64,2). The function converts each of the elements of that array convert it to a desired available precision and store it in an array (predefined type).